# Looking for a way to dynamically autofill a zip code input on a webpage

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am looking for a way (don't need any code examples) to dynamically autofill a zip code input on a website.

I have a site A, which I do not have editing access to. A link on this site allows users to customize a product. Before a user starts customizing, they must input a zipcode which will then refer their customized product to the nearest vendor. I am looking for a way to link this webpage with the zipcode already filled in, so their product is always referred to the same vendor.

I know I could locally inject javascript code into a browser to autofill the inputs. However, I don't know how I could do this dynamically whenever a user clicks the product customization link from site A.

on a side note, whenever someone inputs their zip to site A, it is cached in the browser. So as long as the user has inputted their zip on site A, it will save. Otherwise, it will promptly ask them for a zip before allowing the user to customize a product.

My thoughts so far would be hosting a webpage that loads the HTML of site A, injecting javascript to autofill the zip, and then perform a redirect to site A. (the site is made in react, will that affect loading the HTML?).

I would just like to hear other's thoughts and opinions on this. As I mentioned before, I don't need any code examples, more so just a procedure or algorithm to solve this issue.

Thank you!

Comment: If you don't get much response here, maybe https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ would be more appropriate. StackOverflow usually expects you to have code already and be asking about a specific thing in it.

Comment: Your description is confusing to me, you speak of a "Site A" to which you don't have editing access but that you link to? So there's a Site B that contains the Link that you **_do_** have editing access to? You mention Site A a bunch of times but never mention a Site B. A sentence like "Loads the HTML of Site A, inject Javascript, then perform a redirect to Site A" sounds like 1 of those should be Site B? Or no? Maybe the "hosting a webpage" is Site B?

Comment: @asontu Sorry to be confusing, I wrote this in a hurry. Site B would be the site I would be hosting to perform an autofill on site A. I am wondering if this is a viable solution. I basically just need a way to autofill a zip code on site A which I don't have any editing access to.

Comment: Unless Sites A and B are on the same domain and Site A already has code to look at cookies or localStorage or something, I don't see how this could be possible. You might be thinking of the build-in browser functionality to remember what you filled in in a form in the past. You can't utilize that function from code because of privacy concerns. It's something the browser does beyond the control of whoever coded the website.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `localStorage` or `cookies`. When the user inputs his zipcode just save that in the `docoument cookie`, and on the `document` `onload` event, check if the `cookie` exists, if it does (this means the user visited and has input this field before), then change the value of the input otherwise not (becuase it is his first time visiting the page).

You can also use [`HTML geolocation API`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)